# /wp-content/wflogs/ips.php for reading and writing

Tags: android, ios, wordpress, lynx

what does this mean?

I'm actually in a programming class, and am getting confused over this one! Can anyone explain it without going off topic?? Been following this instructor for 2 days now and he is all over the place...

Comment: It's just a file Wordfence uses to store data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This file is not a core WordPress file; the WordFence Security plugin adds it.

WordFence adds this directory/file to store data without using the database to process security checks before the website connects or accesses the database.

I hope this helps.

Here are some references: https://github.com/PhilippHeuer/wordpress-heroku/issues/16

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/unable-to-open-wp-contentwflogsips-php-for-reading-and-writing/